# How do I find the irreducible representations of a group of matrices?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I have a set of permutation matrices (n x n) of a graph which form a group (the automorphisms).  They are obviously a subgroup of the symmetric group S_n. Is there a way to find the irreducible representations of this group of matrices or, probably just as good, the characters of the irreducible representations?

I am new to this area of group theory (the symmetric group and subgroups) although I know about other finite groups used in the crystallographic symmetry groups along with the usual Schur's lemma, great orthogonality theorem, etc.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This has been discussed on MO a while ago. Searching with Google should unearth useful information.

Comment: A standard strategy is to find subgroups or quotient groups whose representations you understand and induct or restrict their representations. See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer's_theorem_on_induced_characters .

Comment: Every finite group is a subgroup of some symmetric group. Without further information, you are simply asking how to compute the irreducible representation of some given finite group. Have a look at one of the standard books on character theory, such as Serre, or Isaacs.

Comment: As Mariano said, check http://mathoverflow.net/questions/86019/software-package-to-manipulate-representations. For particular examples, you can use GAP function IrreducibleRepreentations.